# Refactoring acts_as_taggable suggestions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, refactoring, acts-as-taggable-on

I have an application with a list of majors and each one is tagged with categories using the acts-as-taggable-on gem.  I have a page where you can explore majors by category.  So, you see the categories and grouped under the category is a list of the majors.

My `categories_controller.rb` file:

```
def index
    @creative = Major.tagged_with("creative arts")
    @engineering = Major.tagged_with("engineering and technology")
    @mechanics = Major.tagged_with("mechanics and construction")
    @transportation = Major.tagged_with("transportation")
    @science = Major.tagged_with("science")
    @math = Major.tagged_with("math")
    @resources = Major.tagged_with("natural resources")
    @healthcare = Major.tagged_with("health care")
    @social_sciences = Major.tagged_with("social sciences")
    @education = Major.tagged_with("education")
    @law = Major.tagged_with("law")
    @management = Major.tagged_with("management and marketing")
    @administrative = Major.tagged_with("administrative and clerical")
    @services = Major.tagged_with("services")
    @tags = Major.tag_counts
end
```

You can see the duplication.  This is compounded on the view template.

Here's part of the `index.html.erb` page:

```
<!-- Creative Arts --> 
<h2 class="major-categories-landing">Creative Arts</h2>

<% @creative.sample(10).each do |creative| %>
<%= link_to creative, class: 'span2 category-landing' do %>
    <%= image_tag creative.image(:similar), class: 'img-polaroid', id: 'category-landing-list' %>
    <p class="category-landing-list-name"><%= creative.name %></p>
<% end %>
 <% end %>

 <%= link_to "View all #{@creative.count} majors in this category.", category_path("creative arts"), class: "view-category-show-page" %>


 <!-- Social Sciences --> 
 <h2 class="major-categories-landing">Social Sciences</h2>

 <% @social_sciences.sample(10).each do |ss| %>
      <%= link_to ss, class: 'span2 category-landing' do %>
    <%= image_tag ss.image(:similar), class: 'img-polaroid', id: 'category-landing-list' %>
    <p class="category-landing-list-name"><%= ss.name %></p>
<% end %>
 <% end %>

 <%= link_to "View all #{@social_sciences.count} majors in this category.", category_path("social sciences"), class: "view-category-show-page" %>
```

and so on for each category.  I have tried `@category = Major.tagged_with(params[:tag])` and many variations to that to no avail.  This is my first time working with acts_as_taggable_on and although I've read the documentation over and over I can't quite figure this out.

I hope to extend this out throughout the application and so I want to figure it out now before I get a lot duplicate code.  Thanks for sharing any ideas or suggestions!!

I am running a rails 3.2.11 app.

**UPDATE**
Here's how much better this is now:
My `categories_controller.rb` file:

```
def index
    @major_categories = ["creative arts", "social sciences", "science", ....]
end
```

My `index.html.erb` page:

```
<% @major_categories.each do |c| %>
    <!-- Title and blue strip -->
    <div class="category-strip">
        <div class="container">
            <h2 class="major-categories-landing"><%= c %></h2>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Show Each Major in this Category --> 
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row-fluid"> 
            <% Major.tagged_with(c).order('RANDOM()').limit(10).each do |major| %>
              <%= link_to major, class: 'span2 category-landing' do %>
                <%= image_tag major.image(:similar), class: 'img-polaroid' %>
                <p class="category-landing-list-name"><%= major.name %></p>
              <% end %>
            <% end %>
        </div>

        <!-- Link to View All Majors -->
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="view-all-category">
                <%= link_to "View all #{Major.tagged_with(c).count} majors in this category.", category_path(c), class: "view-category-show-page" %>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
# in categories_controller.rb
def index
  @categories = ["creative arts", "engineering and technology", 
                 "mechanics and construction", ...]
end

# in index.html.erb
<%= render partial: "category", collection: @categories %>

# in _category.html.erb
<h2 class="major-categories-landing"><%= category.titleize %></h2>

<% Major.tagged_with(category).order('rand()').limit(10).each do |major| %>
  <%= link_to major, class: 'span2 category-landing' do %>
    <%= image_tag major.image(:similar), class: 'img-polaroid', 
                                         id:    'category-landing-list' %>
    <p class="category-landing-list-name"><%= major.name %></p>
  <% end %>
<% end %>

<%= link_to "View all #{Major.tagged_with(category).count} majors in this category.", 
            category_path(category), class: "view-category-show-page" %>
```

Btw: The link to each major is invalid html. A link (because `a` it is an inline element) should not contain a paragraph (because `p` is a box element). Furthermore each link for each category would have the same `id`, but `id`s must be unique in each html document.

Comment: Thank you!  The array worked perfectly!  This is exactly what I was trying to do - it's all looped and no more repetitious code. Seriously, thank you!! Nice catch on the BTW stuff.  I have fixed those things too.